# char* copyStr(const char* someStr)

Tags: c

What are the issues with the following code in C?

```
char* copyStr(const char* someStr)
{
   char buf[100];
   sprintf(buf, “%s”, someStr);
   return buf;
}
```

Comment: What do ***you*** think the issue might be? And what makes you think there even *is* an issue? What happens when you build the code? When you use it? If you get build errors, what errors do you get? If you get unexpected results, what results do you get and what did you expect? If you get a crash, when and where in your code does it crash? Have you tried to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code?

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mre], or how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 major problems in your code:

- `sprintf(buf, “%s”, someStr);` will attempt to store more than 100 bytes to `buf` if the string pointed to by `somStr` is longer than 99 bytes plus the null terminator, causing undefined behavior. This call is equivalent to `strcpy` with the same issue. You should always use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, passing the length of the destination array, thus preventing a buffer overflow.
- returning a pointer to a local array is incorrect as the object will go out of scope immediately upon exiting the function: the caller will invoke undefined behavior dereferencing this pointer.

For your purpose, you should allocate a block of memory, copy the string to it and return a pointer to it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *copyStr(const char *someStr) {
    size_t len = strlen(someStr);
    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, someStr, len + 1);
    }
    return p;
}
```

This is exactly the semantics of the function `strdup` defined in POSIX and standardized the upcoming C23 Standard:

```
char *strdup(const char *s);
```

Comment: You could use both linux and windows. the solution provided by @chqrlie works. The problem was the buffer overflow. Both of the solutions worked just fine.

Comment: @Ali That's why you should always use `snprintf` to lessen the risks of buffer overflows.

Comment: @Ali: the buffer overflow is a problem for long strings, but returning automatic array `buf` is a problem in **all** cases.